# How can I pass the category List to this view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to create SubCategories by passing the category list to the view of the SubCategory.
But I can't use 2 @model in the same view.

Here is my code of the subCategory create view:

```
@model SubCategory
<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Create SubCategory</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="DisplayOrder"></label>
            <input asp-for="DisplayOrder" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DisplayOrder" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Create</button>
        <a asp-controller="SubCategory" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
            Back To List
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried to use IEnumerable and pass to the view as a parameter in the controller. But I couldn't find a way to call it from the view because it is returning an error that I can't use more than one @model statement in my view. Is there any solution or any other way so I can pass my list to this view.

This is my Model of the subCategory:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace BulkyBookWeb.Models
{
    public class SubCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Display Order")]
        [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Display Order must be between 1 and 100")]
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public Category Parent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is where I am returning the View from my SubCategoryController:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    IEnumerable<Category> objCategoryList = _db.Categories;
    return View(objCategoryList); 
}
```

Comment: Show your controller code, where you are returning the view.

Comment: @AakashBashyal I added the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can add below view code

```
  <select class="form-control" id="ParentId" asp-for="ParentId"  asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories"></select>
```

And add below controller code

```
ViewBag.Categories=new SelectList(objCategoryList, "Id", "Name");
```

Id, Name as appropriate

Comment: I did this but it returns this error: " RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BulkyBookWeb.Models.Category>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(objCategoryList, "Id", "Name"); Id, name as appropriate

Comment: It worked but now when I fill the text fields and then select the parent from the dropdown list and submit it always tells me that the parentID field is required and every category in the dropdown list disappear